# How to make a filtering annotation with ManyToMany relation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model with articles, events and people:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Event(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Article(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  publishDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  event = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank=False, null=False)
  persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

An article belongs to an event, and events consist of many articles. Persons appear in many articles and articles contain many persons. The idea is to see which events were most written about inside a given time interval. I did this in a single query:

```
topEvents = Article.objects.filter(publishDate__gt=dateStart)
                           .filter(publishDate__lt=dateEnd)
                           .values('event').annotate(count=Count('id'))
                           .order_by('-count')[:topN]
```

I found that this takes significantly less time than calculating the top N server-side.

Now, the question is, how do I do the same with the ManyToMany relation I have with the Persons? Also, is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify your example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publishDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='articles')
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='articles')
```

Note that there are no `id` fields as Django creates them automatically. Also, both `event` and `persons` on the `Article` class have `related_name` set to 'articles' which  allows us to refer to articles simply by using `event.articles` and `person.articles`.

Now, to get the events and people that are written about most often, you can query directly on their model managers:

```
Event.objects.filter(articles__publishDate__gt=dateStart)\
             .filter(articles__publishDate__lt=dateEnd)\
             .annotate(count=Count('articles')).order_by('-count')

Person.objects.filter(articles__publishDate__gt=dateStart)\
              .filter(articles__publishDate__lt=dateEnd)\
              .annotate(count=Count('articles')).order_by('-count')
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! The queries work, however, they are substantially slower. The one I wrote takes about 15 seconds, while your takes over a minute and a half. Even stranger, when I print some information during this fetching, it seems that the queries themselves are relatively fast, but the whole site lags after the final render_to_response call. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you slice the result (`[:topN]`)?

Comment: Embarrassingly, I forgot :) But still, the resulting counts were tremendously too large. After some SQL analyzing, I found the error: it should be `filter(articles__publishDate__gt=dateStart, articles__publishDate__lt=dateEnd)`. Once again, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
topUsers = Article.objects.filter(publishDate__gt=dateStart)
                          .filter(publishDate__lt=dateEnd)
                          .values('persons').annotate(count=Count('id'))
                          .order_by('-count')[:topN]
```

Comment: Then the exception should show you, what field names are available. What are they?